# Is there a way I can use $set with a condition?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

When I click the first time, the value changes to true, but I can´t find a way to go back to false if I click on it again

I have already tried using a function on the @click, but the only way it worked for me was using $set

Here is my code

```
<div class="kt-header__topbar-wrapper" data-toggle="dropdown" data-offset="10px,0px" @click="$set(hovers, 27, true)">
    <span class="kt-header__topbar-icon" ><i class="flaticon2-search-1"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu-search dropdown-menu-fit dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-top-unround dropdown-menu-anim dropdown-menu-lg" v-show="hovers[27]">
    <div class="kt-quick-search kt-quick-search--dropdown kt-quick-search--result-compact">
        <form method="get" class="kt-quick-search__form">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="flaticon2-search-1"></i></span></div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control kt-quick-search__input" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
                <div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="la la-close kt-quick-search__close"></i></span></div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="kt-quick-search__wrapper kt-scroll" data-scroll="true" data-height="325" data-mobile-height="200"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can use @click="$set..." and if it´s true then change to false and if it´s false change to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be:

```
@click="$set(hovers, 27, !hovers[27])"
```

It should also work fine as a method. Without more information it's difficult to know why that didn't work for you.

e.g.

```
@click="onClick"
```

```js
onClick () {
  this.$set(this.hovers, 27, !this.hovers[27])
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed